# Choosing the derivative of a flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, perturbation-theory, flows

I am looking for something like the Franks' Lemma for flows. The celebrated Franks' Lemma states that: Let $f:M \rightarrow M$ be a $C^1$ diffeomorphism and $S=\{p_1,...,p_k\}$ be a finite set of points in $M$. Denote by $E=\oplus_{i=1}^k T_{p_i}M$ and by $E'=\oplus_{i=1}^k T_{f(p_i)}M$. So for $\varepsilon>0$ small enough there exists $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ such that for any $L=(L_1,...,L_k): E\rightarrow E'$ isomorphism such that
$$||L_i-(Df)_{p_i}||<\delta,$$
for all $i=1,...,k$, there exists a $C^1$ diffeomorphism, say $g:M\rightarrow M$ such that

A) $g(p_i)=f(p_i)$, for all $i=1,...,k$.

B) $(Dg)_{p_i}=L_i$, for all $i=1,...,k$.

C) $g$ is $\varepsilon$-close to $f$ in the $C^1$ topology.

My situation is: Consider a $C^1-$flow $\varphi^t:M\rightarrow M$ and fix a real number $t_0>0$. I want to perturb the derivative $D\varphi^{t_0}$ in a point $p$. It means to chose an linear transformation $L:T_pM\rightarrow T_{\varphi^{t_0}(p)}M$ near $(D\varphi^{t_0})_p$ and find a new flow, say $\psi^t$, such that for some real number $t_1>0$ we have

A') $\psi^{t_1}(p)=\varphi^{t_0}(p)$.

B') $(D\psi^{t_1})_p=L$.

C') The flow $\psi^t$ is near the flow $\varphi^t$ in the $C^1$ topology.

Is there any result is this direction?

Comment: You may want to exclude the degenerate case where $\phi^{t_0}(p) = p$, since then $\psi^{t_1}(p) = p$ which implies $D\psi^{t_1}$ has to have an eigenvalue of 1.

Comment: Hi, @MartinM.W.. Thanks for you comment. A priori I don't see it as a problem. Sure, in this case $L$ is not freely chosen.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this paper by Bonatti-Gourmelon-Vivier https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/ergodic-theory-and-dynamical-systems/article/abs/perturbations-of-the-derivative-along-periodic-orbits/F4D1574CBCEF8C3F09A0C63A105C443F
in which they prove Franks lemma for flows